# ipython shell inside gdb

Tags: python, gdb

I have created a python script which starts an python console "pythonstart.py"

**import sys**

**import subprocess**

**subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python'])**

I am sourcing it from inside gdb

**gdb# source pythonstart.py**

It gives an python console.

**Problem**: When I exit from python console, it returns to gdb, if I press "ENTER" again it again goes back to python console. 
I am not sure why its happening. Once I have quit the python console then why its coming back.

There is another situation: After exit from python, if I don't press "ENTER" on gdb but execute any command and then press "ENTER", problem does not appear.

```
(gdb)
(gdb) source pythonstart.py
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> exit()
(gdb)        <---- Pressing Enter here
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>>
```

I want to stop this from falling back to python console after pressing enter key. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you type a command line, gdb saves it. If you type just a blank line, gdb [re-executes](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Syntax.html#Command-Syntax) the saved command (if any). In your case, typing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will re-execute `source pythonstart.py`.

If the command is a script, it can call the gdb command [`dont-repeat`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#index-don_0027t-repeat-command-1750), which will clear the saved command.

So you can add `gdb.execute("dont-repeat")` to your python script if you don't want a blank line to re-execute the `source` command.